# Is taking $3\sigma$ limits for bivariate correlated random variables as the confidence limits an under estimation?

Tags: probability, statistics, bivariate-distributions

If the two random variables are uncorrelated, $3\sigma$ limit would mean that the random variables lie inside a hyperrectangle with center coordinates being means of random variables. But if two random variables are correlated, is taking a hyperrectangle instead of corresponding hyperellipsoid an under-approximation or altogether not theoretically correct?

Comment: Suppose you are talking about constructing a confidence region for Bivariate normal, then you may refer to, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29860/confidence-interval-of-multivariate-gaussian-distribution for using Hotelling's T to construct the region. Note that the region formed by the Cartaesian product of the marginal CI have a lower coverage probability, and it is not optimal in the sense that the volume of the region is larger.